# Why qsort doesn't work, while sorting an array of structures

Tags: c, struct, unions, qsort

I have an array of such structs

```
typedef union value_
    {
        double d;
        int i;
    } value;

typedef struct number_
{
    char type;
    value val;
}number;
```

type can be `'i'` or `'d'`, depending on either integer or double value is stored in union field.
The array looks as following:

```
Integer value: -3
Double value: 4.84
Integer value: -4
Double value: 1.65
Integer value: 1
Double value: 2.54
Integer value: 2
Double value: -0.09
```

The main thing, is that integers and doubles go one by one. I need to sort this array using qsort in next way: integers should be sorted from lower to higher and doubles vice versa.
I use the following function to compare:

```
int compare(const void *A, const void *B){

    number *a = (number*)A;
    number *b = (number*)B;
    
    if (a->type == b->type) {
        if (a->type =='i') {
            return a->val.i - b->val.i;
        } else {
            if (a->val.d > b->val.d) return -1;
            if (a->val.d < b->val.d) return 1;
            else return 0;
        }
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It is assumed, that if the values in unions have different types, than it returns 0 without comparing, so such sequence, as int,double,int,double should be saved. But the result is following:

```
Integer value: -1
Integer value: -5
Double value: 0.20
Integer value: 2
Double value: -0.04
Double value: -2.69
Integer value: 4
Integer value: 5
Double value: 2.04
Integer value: 3
```

Why does it change doubles with integers, if it should return 0 in that case?

Comment: Since your `compare` functions returns `equal` for two different types the final outcome will be unpredictable. You might change it so that all integers are lower than all double values, or vice versa.

Comment: thank you, i've suspected that, such comparison is a bad idea

Comment: I don't think you can use the standard `qsort` function to do what you want. If your `compare` function returns `0` for different types then, as pointed oyt by @500-InternalServerError, you have unpredictable/undefined behaviour; however, if you return `+1` or `-1`, then the `int` and `double` types will be shuffled so that they are consecutive in the list, ***not*** in their original, 'interlaced' order. You'' need your own sort function.

Comment: Change `typedef struct number_` to `typedef struct number`. There's no reason to add that underscore.

Comment: i've already followed his their's advice, and make it to estimate integers lower than doubles. It can't save such sequence, as I wanted, but sort everything fine

Comment: from qsort man page : " If two members compare as equal, their order in the sorted array is undefined.". I don't think that what you want, you need to either add an information in your structure (the structure position in your array) or use another sort function that will preserve order

Comment: Unlikely to cause any problems, but "casting away" `const` leads to undefined behavior. You should work with `const number*` variables.

Comment: @Tom's, why don't you want to write it as an answer?

Comment: @Albus_Dalbador Because i'm not quite sure what you want to do. English is not my language, so from time to time I have difficulty to really understant what someone want. If you want to have "smallest int - biggest double - ... - bigger int - smallest double" as the result, i don't think qsort alone will suffice. What do you want to do exactly ? can you describe it (with desired output) ?

Comment: There is no need to use 'int' because 'double' can represent all values of int with full precision. Don't play with a union just use 'double' everywhere

Comment: @tstanisl If the native `int` type is 64 bits, then a `double` can't represent it with full accuracy. There will also be potential 'rounding errors' even on platforms with 32 bit integers. `int` and `double` are ***very*** different types with ***very*** different behaviours.

Comment: @Adrian Mole  yes, I know that 'int' could be theoretically 64bit but it is almost universally 32 with some legacy platforms with 16 bits. What potential rounding errors do you mean?

Comment: @tstanisl IIRC, an integer can only be *exactly* represented in IEEE-754 `double` if it fulfils certain requirements about being composed of powers of 2. When reaching the limits of 32-bit integers, I'm sure there will be issues moving the 2's complement value into the IEEE mantissa. Not 100% sure, though.

Comment: @Adrian Mole, ieee754 'double' has 53 mantissa bit. It's more than enough to represent all values of typical 32bit 'int'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to preserve the original list's 'interlocked pattern' of `int` and `double` types, yet sort each set of `int` and `double` values, then you can't use the standard `qsort` function *as is* on the complete list.

However, what you can do is to separate the `int` and `double` entries into new lists, sort those separately, then merge the two sorted lists back into the original, taking either an `int` or `double` entry from the relevant sorted list, depending on the type of the entry in the original list.

Here's a possible implementation (using the `compare` function from your code unchanged – though you'd get better performance for large lists if you made two, type-specific, comparison functions for use with the separated lists):

```c
void printlist(number* list, size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (list[i].type == 'i') printf("%d ", list[i].val.i);
        else printf("%lf ", list[i].val.d);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    number list[] = {
        { 'i', { .i = -3} },   { 'd', { .d = 1.65} },
        { 'i', { .i = -4} },   { 'd', { .d = 4.85} },
        { 'i', { .i =  1} },   { 'd', { .d = -.09} },
        { 'i', { .i =  2} },   { 'd', { .d = 2.54} },
    };
    size_t Tcount = sizeof(list) / sizeof(*list), Icount = 0, Dcount = 0; // Counts for total, ints and doubles
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Tcount; ++i) {
        if (list[i].type == 'i') ++Icount;
        else ++Dcount;
    }
    // Display original list ...
    printlist(list, Tcount);
    number* Ilist = malloc(sizeof(number) * Icount);
    number* Dlist = malloc(sizeof(number) * Dcount);
    size_t Iindex = 0, Dindex = 0;
    // Separate lists ...
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Tcount; ++i) {
        if (list[i].type == 'i') Ilist[Iindex++] = list[i];
        else Dlist[Dindex++] = list[i];
    }
    // Sort each list separately ...
    qsort(Ilist, Icount, sizeof(number), compare);
    qsort(Dlist, Dcount, sizeof(number), compare);
    // Merge sorted lists ...
    Iindex = 0, Dindex = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < Tcount; ++i) {
        if (list[i].type == 'i') list[i] = Ilist[Iindex++];
        else list[i] = Dlist[Dindex++];
    }
    // Display sorted list ...
    printlist(list, 8);
    // Clean up ...
    free(Ilist);
    free(Dlist);
    return 0;
}
```